$\{x\}, [x]$ and $x$ are in a geometric progression . Find least positive integer n for which $x^n > 100$
 PRE RMO 2017 P14 :

Suppose $x$ is a positive real number such that $\{x\}$, $[x]$ and $x$ are in a geometric progression. Find the least positive integer $n$ such that $x^n > 100$. (Here $[x]$ denotes the integer part of $x$ and $\{x\} = x - [x]$.)

The intial steps to the question are quite simple.
Given $\{x\} = x - [x] $
Let $\{x\} = a$
$$[x] = ar$$
$$x = ar^2$$
$$ar^2 - ar - a = 0 $$
$$r^2 - r - 1 = 0 $$
$$r = \frac{1 \pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
$$r = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \quad (r \text{ - is positive})$$
Since $[x]$ is an integer, $a$ must be equal to $\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $x = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$
Now, to find the value of $n$, we must solve:
$$\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n > 100$$
I've tried solving the question further but I couldn't as the value of $\log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$ is not given.
So, is there any other way to solve the inequality ?

So $x=\phi$ is the golden ratio. The Fibonacci sequence grows exponentially with $\phi$ as a growth factor so you can use that. The most useful expression of this fact in this case is that $F_n=\lfloor {\frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{5}}}\rceil$ where the brackets mean rounding to the nearest integer.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Given $x=(1+\sqrt5)/2$, you can consider the properties of $x^3=2+\sqrt5$.
We have $x^3>4$, so $x^9>64$ and $x^{3×7/2}>128$. This implies
$x^{10}>\sqrt[3]{64×128^2}=\sqrt[3]{1048576}.$
At the same time $x^3<5$ and
$x^6=(2+\sqrt5)^2=9+4\sqrt5<18,$
so $x^9<90$.
Conclude the minimal $n$ from there.
